# Image Resource Memory

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, memory-leaks

Since I had a really nasty problem with an not too obvious unmanaged resource last month, I got a little hypernervous regarding memory leaking problems.
I was just coding on a very simple test app with a button with two different pictures on it and noticed I am not quite sure if I have a "problem" here or not...

If I have 2 picture resources Pic1 and Pic2 and an ImageButton-Object, which is just some object inherited from UserControl and with a changed OnPaint:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPaint(e);
   //stuff
   if (this.keyStatus))
   { this.imageButton.DefaultImage = Resource1.Pic1; }
   else
   { this.imageButton.DefaultImage = Resource1.Pic2; }
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.defaultImage, this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

Beside OnPaint not being a good place for assigning DefaultImage (its just here to show you what I mean in a short piece of code), I am just assinging a reference to my precompiled resource here, am I? I am not creating a copy as I would if I would call it with `new Bitmap(Resource1.Pic1)`.
So if I change keyStatus every 5 seconds, I would have a very annoying picture on my screen with a lot of changing, but no problems that the picture changing or turning it invisible from time to time leaks memory. Correct?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The resource designer does not do a very good job of generating proper code.  The `Pic1` and `Pic2` properties should have been methods.  They return a *new* bitmap every single time you use the property, that bitmap should be disposed after use.  So in this rather horribly borken code snippet in all likelihood you have to dispose imageButton.DefaultImage if it isn't null.  Usually, there is no 100% guarantee that this image did not come from somewhere else and therefore might be used elsewhere.  Hard to comment on bad code.

Comment: @HansPassant What.. what? Okay, thanks for the heads up, that changes everything. I'll change my answer ; Zorakh doesn't seem to get what you mean.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, though I am not quite sure what you mean with Pic1 and Pic2 being methods returning a new instance of bitmap. I specifically included them as resources in my project in order to use the same (and only) copy every time and not being in need to dispose instances on the way. And if I got atlaste's answer right, this is really the case here, so I woud not have to worry about this here (in fact I do not observe memory problems atm).

Or is it like this in my sample above, but it would be better to do it like you said? In that case: Could you tell me the advantages?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

**How object references work**

Say you have a random object. The object is a class type (not a value type) and not `IDisposable`. Basically that means the following:

```
// y is some object
var x = y;
```

Now, x doesn't copy all the data from y, but simply makes a new reference to the contents of y. Simple.

To ensure that there won't be memory leaks, the GC keeps track of all objects and (periodically) checks which objects are reachable. If an object is still reachable, it won't be deleted - if it's not, it will be removed.

**And then there was unmanaged code**

As long as you stick to managed code, everything is fine. The moment you run into unmanaged code (say: GDI+, which is the native counterpart of a lot of System.Drawing stuff) you need to do extra book-keeping to get rid of the code. After all, the .NET runtime doesn't know much about the unmanaged data - it merely knows that there is a pointer. Therefore, the GC will cleanup the pointer, but not the data -- which would result in memory leaks.

Therefore, the guys from .NET added `IDisposable`. By implementing IDisposable, you can implement extra (unmanaged) cleanup, such as releasing unmanaged memory, closing files, closing sockets, etc.

Now, the GC knows about finalizers, which are implemented as part of the Disposable pattern (details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx ). However, you usually don't want to wait for a GC run to clean up unmanaged resources. So, it's generally a good idea to call `Dispose()` when an object can be cleaned up and has unmanaged resources.

As is the case with `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, which implements `IDisposable`.

In most cases, you can simply wrap `IDisposable` in a `using` statement, which will call 'Dispose()' for you in a nice try/finally clause. e.g.:

```
using (var myBitmap = new Bitmap(...))
{
    // use myBitmap
}
// myBitmap including all resources are gone.
```

**What about resource bitmaps**

@HansPassant pointed out that resource bitmaps generate a new `Bitmap` every time you access a bitmap property. This basically means that the bitmaps are copied and need to be disposed.

In other words:

```
// Free the old bitmap if it exists:
if (this.imageButton.DefaultImage != null)
{
    this.imageButton.DefaultImage.Dispose();
    this.imageButton.DefaultImage = null;
}

// assign new imageButton.DefaultImage
```

So, this solves the memory leak, but will give you a lot of data that is copied around.

**If you don't want to dispose**

Here comes the part why I was surprised by the remark from Hans :) Basically you assign a `Bitmap` to a button every time, so you don't want to copy the data over and over again - that makes little sense.

Therefore, you might get the idea to wrap the resource into a 'static' container and simply don't deallocate it at all:

```
static Bitmap myPic1 = Resource1.Pic1;
static Bitmap myPic2 = Resource1.Pic2;

...

if (this.keyStatus))
{ 
    this.imageButton.DefaultImage = myPic1; 
}
else
{ 
    this.imageButton.DefaultImage = myPic2; 
}
```

This works, but will give you issues if you at some point decide to generate images as well. To illustrate, say we change the code like this::

```
if (this.keyStatus))
{ 
    this.imageButton.DefaultImage = myPic1; // #1 don't dispose
}
else
{ 
    Bitmap myPic3 = CreateFancyBitmap();    // #2 do dispose
    this.imageButton.DefaultImage = myPic3; 
}
```

Now, the issue here is with the combination. `myPic1` is a static object and shouldn't be disposed. On the other hand, `myPic3` is not, and should be disposed. If you do call `Dispose()`, you'll get a nasty exception at #1, because the data is no longer there. There's no proper way to distinguish the two.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, that is why I was asking, there was a lot of IDisposables around, but in this very simple case I did not feel as if I really needed to Dispose something since I was only passing around this reference.
Dou you get what Hans Passant means in his comment with Pic1 and Pic2 being methods returning new bitmaps? It is clear I would need to dispose in that case, but didn't we just agree this is not the case here?

Comment: @Zorakh I assume my updated answer answers your question?